# vs code editor crazy since 1.9

Tags: visual-studio-code

Wondering if you guys were having the same experience. Since update 1.9 I am fighting with vs code to leave my code alone. It keeps reformatting at the most unfortunate of times and has me contemplating switching back to Sublime text.

e.g.

When trying to type get this:

```
{{> userSettings}}
{{> userGeneralSettings }}
```

[image]

It keeps reformatting to this:

```
{{> userSettings}} {{> userGeneralSettings }}
```

Other example of bogus editing support

[trying to assign function to property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrVlr.gif)

And Emmet and Intellisense keep combatting each other.

Besides that when editing html it keeps drawing selections over my code and when I press enter it deletes the tags.

I've tried fiddling around with the settings but haven't found how to disable this annoying behaviour.

Is anybody else having this experience?

Comment: tweet them about the issue, or raise an issue in github

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with one of the extensions. Don't know which one was messing with my code. Thank you to the vs code devs for including a one shot 'disable all extensions'.

VS Code faith restored.

If I find the culprit will update this post.

Sorry for being a whining sob..